# Postgres: What's the best index for 'SELECT * FROM t WHERE a < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY b'?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE a < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY b
```

What is the best index ?

What if we have another query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE a < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND c < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY b
```

What is the best index?
Is there one index that can serve both queries?

EDIT: I apologize for changing the query after some answers were already written. The new queries better reflect the situation I have.

EDIT: Additional potentially relevant details:

1) 'SELECT *' is written to simplify the question (actual query does not use *).

2) I can break up the queries using LIMIT if it improves overall performance.

Comment: You need to define what is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP? It changes the question on whether it is just a placeholder for a constant, or, if it's an actual column in table t. Also, the type of the columns may be important, you should supply the CREATE TABLE ddl. Also some sample data and indication of spread may be helpful in deciding which is the best index for you.

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the magical "constant" provided by Postgres that is always equal to the current time. I don't know if it's technically correct to call this dynamic system-managed variable a "constant".

Comment: None of the indexes will be useful if _majority_ of your data belongs to past (i.e. less than current_timestamp). You're also using `SELECT *`.

Comment: @SalmanA, in one of the comments bellow, he pointed out he is using a limit.

Comment: I wrote * to keep the question simple but the actual implementation does not use *. Most data belongs to the future (> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) but your point is well taken, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you want in this particular case is a partial index (filtered index). You can find the documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html

```
CREATE INDEX idx___xxx ON table (b)
     WHERE a<0;
```

Edit as the question has been changed: this answer is good as long as the where clause is using a constant and that constant is known prior to the index operation.

Comment: This answer has merits. A partial index could be quite useful, if the number of selected rows is less than 5%, though.

Comment: My original question had 'a < 0' but this has been changed to 'a < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. Since CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a non-constant constant (if that makes sense), would this still work well with a partial index?

Comment: It is not possible  to use a partial index here because the comparison value change with time (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Answer (score 2):

The best index to your case is a multi-column index in this order: `(a, c, b)`

For the first query, the planner will filter by `a < 0` and use the second column to order (no sorting required at the end of the query).

For the second case, the planner will filter by `a < 0 and c < 0` and use the third column to sort the records found (also skipping the sorting at the end).

The Dumitrescu Bogdan's answer works, but requires a sort procedure at the end and, in the second case, the number of records filtered are smaller than on my approach.

Good reference for learning about multicolumn indexes: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

Also, this one explains how the index can avoid a sorting operation at the end: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by

**Update**

After the author's update, it is required two indexes to avoid the sorting operation.

For the first case, you will need an index on `(a, b)`.
For the second case, you will need an index on `(a, c, b)`. With this configuration, in both cases, you avoid the final sorting operation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I swapped 'b' and 'c' when writing the second query by accident. Does this change the answer?

Comment: @RayZhang, yes, it changes the answer... In this case, the order of the columns should be (a,c,b). When you have time, take a look at the link I left in the question. It explains very well why the order matters

Comment: I don't think Postgres can avoid the sort with the proposed indexes (for `order by b` with no index that has `b` as a leading column.)

Comment: @viniciusjssouza I removed the down vote. I [wrongly] assumed the filtering conditions were not selective enough.

Comment: @spencer7593 you are right. The author changed the question, removing the benefit of avoiding the sorting on the first case

Answer (score 1):

An index that may work is:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ix_t_006 on t (a, c);
```

After repeated testing, I found this to be an "OK" index for handling both of your queries. You see that this indexes handles your WHERE clauses but ORDER BY b isn't being handled.

Instead the ORDER BY is being handled by an in memory quicksort. This is because a "bitmap index scan" is being done on columns (a, c) which means any implied sort order will be undone. So creating an index on (a, c, b) will not be effective since the order will be undone, so, the only thing we have working is an index on (a, c).

The thing that's missing from your question is the quantity of results that you will get and whether an in memory quicksort is satisfactory.

Please use EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ... to verify.

The first query resulted in:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE a < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY b;

 Sort  (cost=59.91..61.61 rows=680 width=12) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: b
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=9.42..27.92 rows=680 width=12) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (a < 0)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_t_006  (cost=0.00..9.25 rows=680 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (a < 0)
 Planning time: 0.091 ms
 Execution time: 0.042 ms
```

The second query resulted in:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE a < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND c < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY b;

 Sort  (cost=33.30..33.86 rows=227 width=12) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: b
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=11.01..24.41 rows=227 width=12) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((a < 0) AND (c < 0))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_t_006  (cost=0.00..10.95 rows=227 width=0)(actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((a < 0) AND (c < 0))
```

After repeated testing, I found that my answer had to be edited repeatedly. At one point, I found myself wanting to delete my answer since I kept changing it so much. I'm disappointed that I hadn't found you an answer that helped you with the ORDER BY.

I think the key is to keep trying with the EXPLAIN ANALYZE until you get it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I swapped 'b' and 'c' when writing the second query by accident. Does this change the answer?

Comment: Ray, your updated question required a rewrite of the answer

Comment: Ray, I rewrote my entire answer after testing the indexes out with EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: Thank you for putting in that effort. I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: @StephenQuan, your approach is not optimal because it is not able to filter the rows. The executor would have to sweep the index until it finds the rows which matches the filters on a and c. The order of b does not guarentee the order of b and c. This links provides explanation on the topic: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by

Answer (score 0):

Probably no index will be better than a heap scan (aka full table scan).

You don't include table stats, but I would assume the filtering conditions retrieve more than 5% of the rows (most likely). If this is the case a Heap Scan will be faster than any index, and less resource intensive.

What percent of rows do those queries return? 50%, 5%, 0.5%?

Comment: The query returns <1% of rows in one use case and ~5-10% of rows in another use case. However, in the second use case I have the option to break up the query using a eg LIMIT 1000 clause, which has other potential benefits for the application I am working on.

Comment: Then, the indexes can be useful in the first case. In the second case, probably no index will be better than a heap scan.

Comment: As the query is accessing historical data, the @TheImpaler answer would be correct, unless a limit was used. But, as the author of the questions pointed out, he is using a limit, which make the index useful

Comment: @viniciusjssouza Isn't the LIMIT applied after the initial scan or filter is already done, since the results must be sorted before LIMIT can work? Can you clarify the order of operations that allows LIMIT to keep the index useful?

Comment: @RayZhang the query executor will sweep the index collecting the results until it reaches the limit you supplied. As the records already are sorted (by the index itself), there is no need to a final sorting.

Comment: @RayZhang this links explains the technique: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by